# Control Panel base url not updating... how to fix?

Tags: control-panel

We recently changed the URL for an EE site currently in development.  We changed the URL entries on the General Configuration page.

We found that we could not change these entries on the General Configuration page, but could do so via the Edit Config page.

These changes are now being reflected in the General Configuration page, but the Control Panel is still trying to open pages on the old URL.  This is OK after a fashion (the old URL is aliased to the new one), but is causing EE to throw CORS errors for some plug-ins (in particular Assets).

Anyone know how I can coerce EE into recognising the new URL to the Control Panel index page?

We're using a simple installation of EE 2.9.2 (not MSM).

Thanks in advance for whatever help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check both the /index.php and /admin.php files... also /system/index.php.

Also, it sounds like there might possibly be an actual config file somewhere if you weren't able to edit under General Configurations. It might be here /system/expressionengine/config/config.php.

NOTE: The file structure for EE can be set up in different ways so if you don't have a "system" directory in root, you're going to have to find it... It might not be named "system".